# Splitting or decomposing LineString into original single lines or segments using shapely?

Tags: python, geometry, shapely

I am trying to split a LineString into single segments:

```
from shaply import LineString,MultiPoint
from shapely.ops import split
xp = [-2,1,2,2.5,4,1,-1,2,4,5,6]
yp = [-2,1,1,0,1,2,2,3,4,4,4]
list_of_point = list(zip(xp,yp))
profile = LineString(list_of_point)
```

At the moment I am using `split`:

```
points_to_split = MultiPoint([Point(x,y) for x,y in profile.coords[1:]])
splitted = split(profile,points_to_split)
for i in splitted:print(i)
```

I've got the expected result but it seems quite overcomplicating a process that should be quite easy to handle internally.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

you can simplify it to a one-liner, by building geometries without `split`

```
splitted = [geom.LineString([profile.coords[i], profile.coords[i+1]]) for i in range(len(profile.coords) - 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks but I've got  840 µs for your solution vs 54.9 ns for mine in my machine so is not really efficient.